# Net Connection Connect Failed in php Video Recorder

Tags: php, webcam

I am using php video plugin of http://www.videowhisper.com/ Capture video from webcam and save it in php. It is working fine on live demo but when i download it and run in my local machine or upload to my server and run then i got following error
[image]

Comment: Could you show your PHP code or perhaps ask that this get migrated to SuperUser or Ask Ubuntu if it's purely a user level question for your choice of OS?

Comment: I am on Windows OS.I have all administrator rights setup for the directory and php. It is not the problem of server because i have tried it in mylocalmachine and at different servers too.

Answer (score 0):

RTMP Address

Change in your server settings.

rtmp://localhost/VideoWhisper

to a new rtmp address

I have this and works:

rtmp://stream.ssh101.com/PublishingPoint7

You make here your free RTMP Address:

http://www.ssh101.com/

You can test here your RTMP Address:

http://www.videowhisper.com/demos/admin/vw_connectiontester.html